# How do I change the slashes that get appended to quotes from mysql, back to their original form for display

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-encode

I am trying to allow the user to store a string in a database which will often contain an anchor tag and or multiple paragraphs. I am posting to my database and mysql appends on the `\` to quotes and such via the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. Now when I make a call to retrieve the information back I recieve a string like this

`Pop some popcorn, make some hot cocoa and let your kids enjoy these movies during their winter break! Find more lists of books <a href="\'#\'">Here</a>\nThis should be a new line of text.`

This actually outputs correctly up until the new line character where it actually just displays `\n` instead of a line break.

I am trying to handle this string with javascript to output it in the correct format. I am trying to do this

```
var msg = $("<textarea>").html( (response.banner_msg) ).text();
$(".booklist-msg").html(msg.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
```

But this doesn't work. I have also tried using `htmlentity()` within my php post call and then on my get calling `html_entity_decode()`. I would also like to add in `stripslashes()` because this paragraph is going to be editable and the slashes continuously build on each other every time I update.

**This is my post function**

```
function updateBooklistDetails($second_db, $booklist) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($booklist[name]);
    $img = mysql_real_escape_string($booklist[img]);
    $msg = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($booklist[msg]));
    $auth = mysql_real_escape_string($booklist[auth]);
    $id = $booklist[listId];
    $res = $second_db->query( $second_db->prepare("UPDATE `BookList` SET booklist_name = %s, author = %s, banner_msg = %s, image_url = %s WHERE booklist_id = %s ", $name, $auth, $msg, $img, $id) );
    return $res;
}
```

**This is my get function**

```
function retrieveBooklistInfo( $request ) {
    $second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, "saic3_LibraryIndex", 
    DB_HOST);
    $id = $request['id'];
    $id = (string)$id;
    $booklist = getBooklistById($second_db, $id );
    $booklist->booklist_name = stripslashes($booklist->booklist_name);
    $booklist->banner_msg = html_entity_decode($booklist->banner_msg, ENT_QUOTES);
    $booklist->books = getBooklistBooksById($second_db, $id );
    $booklist->category = getBooklistCategoryById($second_db, $id );
    $second_db->close();
    return $booklist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to think it out loud. I wasn't using the `.replace()` correctly..

It should have been

`$(".booklist-msg").html(msg.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />'));`

and not

`$(".booklist-msg").html(msg.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));`

I forgot to escape the escape character.
and as for the strip slash problem I used

`$booklist->banner_msg = str_replace("\'", "'", $booklist->banner_msg);`

in order to only strip the slashes from the qoutes and not the new line characters.